# Convert text to int64 categorical in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I have some artist names in `data['artist']` that I would like to convert to a categorical column via:

```
x = data['artist'].astype('category').cat.codes
x.dtype
```

Returns:

```
dtype('int32')
```

I am getting negative numbers which suggests some sort of overflow situation. So, I'd like to use `np.int64` instead but I can't find documentation on how to accomplish this.

```
x = data['artist'].astype('category').cat.codes.astype(np.int64)
x.dtype
```

Gives

```
dtype('int64')
```

but it is clear that the int32 gets converted to int64 and so the negative value is still present

```
x = data['artist'].astype('category').cat.codes.astype(np.int64)
x.min()

-1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have `NaN` in column `artist`, so code is `-1`:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'artist':[np.nan,'y','z','x','y','z']})

x = data['artist'].astype('category').cat.codes
print x
0   -1
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
5    2
dtype: int8
```

For checking `NaN` you can use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html):

```
print data[data.artist.isnull()]
  artist
0    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the root of the problem. Out of curiosity, what happens if the number of categories is greater than int32? Is there a way to force int64?

Comment: Hard question, but I think `categories` are used if  string variable consisting of only a few different values. [see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html). So I think it is `int32` for save memory.

Comment: That would be over 2 billion artists... I tried `codes = pd.Series(range(2**33)).astype('category').cat.codes` but killed my kernel. Expanding 2^2, 2^8, 2^15, however, the dtype increases from int8 to int16 to int32.