# pandas dataframe convert column type to string or categorical

Tags: pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, categorical-data

How do I convert a single column of a pandas dataframe to type string? In the df of housing data below I need to convert zipcode to string so that when I run linear regression, zipcode is treated as categorical and not numeric. Thanks!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'zipcode': {17384: 98125, 2680: 98107, 722: 98005, 18754: 98109, 14554: 98155}, 'bathrooms': {17384: 1.5, 2680: 0.75, 722: 3.25, 18754: 1.0, 14554: 2.5}, 'sqft_lot': {17384: 1650, 2680: 3700, 722: 51836, 18754: 2640, 14554: 9603}, 'bedrooms': {17384: 2, 2680: 2, 722: 4, 18754: 2, 14554: 4}, 'sqft_living': {17384: 1430, 2680: 1440, 722: 4670, 18754: 1130, 14554: 3180}, 'floors': {17384: 3.0, 2680: 1.0, 722: 2.0, 18754: 1.0, 14554: 2.0}})
print (df)
       bathrooms  bedrooms  floors  sqft_living  sqft_lot  zipcode
722         3.25         4     2.0         4670     51836    98005
2680        0.75         2     1.0         1440      3700    98107
14554       2.50         4     2.0         3180      9603    98155
17384       1.50         2     3.0         1430      1650    98125
18754       1.00         2     1.0         1130      2640    98109
```

Answer (score 136):

You need [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['zipcode'] = df.zipcode.astype(str)
#df.zipcode = df.zipcode.astype(str)
```

---

For converting to `categorical`:

```
df['zipcode'] = df.zipcode.astype('category')
#df.zipcode = df.zipcode.astype('category')
```

Another solution is [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html):

```
df['zipcode'] = pd.Categorical(df.zipcode)
```

Sample with data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'zipcode': {17384: 98125, 2680: 98107, 722: 98005, 18754: 98109, 14554: 98155}, 'bathrooms': {17384: 1.5, 2680: 0.75, 722: 3.25, 18754: 1.0, 14554: 2.5}, 'sqft_lot': {17384: 1650, 2680: 3700, 722: 51836, 18754: 2640, 14554: 9603}, 'bedrooms': {17384: 2, 2680: 2, 722: 4, 18754: 2, 14554: 4}, 'sqft_living': {17384: 1430, 2680: 1440, 722: 4670, 18754: 1130, 14554: 3180}, 'floors': {17384: 3.0, 2680: 1.0, 722: 2.0, 18754: 1.0, 14554: 2.0}})
```

```
print (df)
       bathrooms  bedrooms  floors  sqft_living  sqft_lot  zipcode
722         3.25         4     2.0         4670     51836    98005
2680        0.75         2     1.0         1440      3700    98107
14554       2.50         4     2.0         3180      9603    98155
17384       1.50         2     3.0         1430      1650    98125
18754       1.00         2     1.0         1130      2640    98109

print (df.dtypes)
bathrooms      float64
bedrooms         int64
floors         float64
sqft_living      int64
sqft_lot         int64
zipcode          int64
dtype: object

df['zipcode'] = df.zipcode.astype('category')

print (df)
       bathrooms  bedrooms  floors  sqft_living  sqft_lot zipcode
722         3.25         4     2.0         4670     51836   98005
2680        0.75         2     1.0         1440      3700   98107
14554       2.50         4     2.0         3180      9603   98155
17384       1.50         2     3.0         1430      1650   98125
18754       1.00         2     1.0         1130      2640   98109

print (df.dtypes)
bathrooms       float64
bedrooms          int64
floors          float64
sqft_living       int64
sqft_lot          int64
zipcode        category
dtype: object
```

Comment: `df.zipcode = df.zipcode.astype('category')` works. No error message and dtypes shows correctly. But sklearn linear_model assigns the same weight as when it's type int. Trying for type str `df.zipcode = df.zipcode.astype(str)`--> `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` Then zipcode shows as type object, and linear_model gives it the same weight as before. Trying to recreate assignment done in graphlab which had zipcode as str and gave much lower training error. Thanks again!

Comment: Any idea how this works for very large `DataFrame`s?  I'm just curious if there is any sort of garbage collection problems in over-writing the column.  My DF is so large that I don't want 2 deep copies of it, so after converting to `category` or whatever, is there still just as much data in memory?  (Or potentially even less?  Since `category` has mapping which allows for `int`s to be stored under the hood.)

Comment: @MikeWilliamson - `if there is any sort of garbage collection` - I have no idea. But there is main question how many unique values of categorical. Check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148032/convert-text-to-int64-categorical-in-pandas/37148073#comment61834761_37148073)

Comment: What's the difference between the `.astype` and `df.Categorical` approaches?

Comment: I converted a column using both `apply` and `astype` methods, e.g. `df1.iloc[:,9:].apply(str)`, but when I checked the datatype of the column `df.info()` still returns int64. I don't need to assign that call to a df do I?

Comment: @Edison - yop, need assign back like `df1.iloc[:,9:] = df1.iloc[:,9:].astype(str)`

Comment: @jezrael Thanks! :) Btw, I am doing this conversion for `CatBoostClassifier` since it wants strings. But I have two numerical columns `age` and `distance`. Do I drop them or also convert those to strings? Seems weird to have ints/floats that are strings.

Comment: @Edison - Honeslty never working with `CatBoost`, so not idea, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks. If anyone else knows the answer please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

**With pandas >= 1.0 there is now a dedicated string datatype:**

**1)** You can convert your column to this pandas **string datatype** using [.astype('string')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html):

```
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype('string')
```

**2)** This is different from using `str` which sets the pandas **object datatype**:

```
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype(str)
```

**3)** For changing into **categorical datatype** use:

```
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype('category')
```

You can see this difference in datatypes when you look at the info of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'zipcode_str': [90210, 90211] ,
    'zipcode_string': [90210, 90211],
    'zipcode_category': [90210, 90211],
})

df['zipcode_str'] = df['zipcode_str'].astype(str)
df['zipcode_string'] = df['zipcode_str'].astype('string')
df['zipcode_category'] = df['zipcode_category'].astype('category')

df.info()

# you can see that the first column has dtype object
# while the second column has the new dtype string
# the third column has dtype category
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------            --------------  -----   
 0   zipcode_str       2 non-null      object  
 1   zipcode_string    2 non-null      string  
 2   zipcode_category  2 non-null      category
dtypes: category(1), object(1), string(1)
```

From the docs:

> The 'string' extension type solves several issues with object-dtype
> NumPy arrays:
>
> 1. You can accidentally store a mixture of strings and non-strings in an
>    object dtype array. A StringArray can only store strings.
> 2. object dtype breaks dtype-specific operations like
>    DataFrame.select_dtypes(). There isn’t a clear way to select just text
>    while excluding non-text, but still object-dtype columns.
> 3. When reading code, the contents of an object dtype array is less clear
>    than string.

More info on working with the new string datatype can be found here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html

Comment: If we need to convert columns to string for CatBoost should we use str or string? I tried using apply(str) but python says my data is still int64.

Comment: How can we convert to categorical many columns simulteaneously?

Answer (score 11):

Prior answers focused on nominal data (e.g. unordered). If there is a reason to impose order for an ordinal variable, then one would use:

```
# Transform to category
df['zipcode_category'] = df['zipcode_category'].astype('category')

# Add ordered category
df['zipcode_ordered'] = df['zipcode_category']

# Setup the ordering
df.zipcode_ordered.cat.set_categories(
    new_categories = [90211, 90210], ordered = True, inplace = True
)

# Output IDs
df['zipcode_ordered_id'] = df.zipcode_ordered.cat.codes
print(df)
#  zipcode_category zipcode_ordered  zipcode_ordered_id
#            90210           90210                   1
#            90211           90211                   0
```

More details on setting ordered categories can be found at the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/) website:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#sorting-and-order

Answer (score 5):

To convert a column into a string type (that will be an *object* column per se in pandas), use `astype`:

```
df.zipcode = zipcode.astype(str)
```

If you want to get a `Categorical` column, you can pass the parameter `'category'` to the function:

```
df.zipcode = zipcode.astype('category')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I try these methods (and others) I get the same error: `train_more_features['zipcode'] = pd.Categorical(train_more_features.zipcode)`                                         `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`