# Pandas: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file with about 7000 rows. I'm trying to add latitude and longitude through georeferencing them in python pandas. But now I am receiving a problem "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'". The code is working and gives me some output. I do not understand what's the problem is, because when I checked the types of columns I need, they're all string types.

```
df["lat"]=0.0
df["long"]=0.0
import geocoder
for i in range(1,len(df)) :
    req = df.iloc[i]['country']+','+ df.iloc[i]['province'] +','+ df.iloc[i]['winery']
    g = geocoder.google(req, key='.....')
    if(g.latlng):
        df.set_value(i,'lat',g.latlng[0])
        df.set_value(i,'long',g.latlng[1])
```

---

```
Unnamed: 0      int64
country        object
province       object
region_1       object
winery         object
lat           float64
long          float64
dtype: object
```

---

Thank you for any help!

### -----

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-77abfb24b881> in <module>
      4 import geocoder
      5 for i in range(1,len(df)) :
----> 6     req = df.iloc[i]['country']+','+ df.iloc[i]['province'] +','+ df.iloc[i]['winery']
      7     g = geocoder.google(req, key='.....')
      8     if(g.latlng):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error that references where in the code the issue was?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-77abfb24b881> in <module>
      4 import geocoder
      5 for i in range(1,len(df)) :
----> 6     req = df.iloc[i]['country']+','+ df.iloc[i]['province'] +','+ df.iloc[i]['winery']
      7     g = geocoder.google(req, key='......')
      8     if(g.latlng):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this line of the error:

```
----> 6     req = df.iloc[i]['country']+','+ df.iloc[i]['province'] +','+ df.iloc[i]['winery']
```

There is a value within one of those columns that is a float type which cannot be string concatenated. You could force them to `str()` every time before concatenating if you don't want to find and correct the source data.

Like this:

```py
req = str(df.iloc[i]['country']) + ',' + str(df.iloc[i]['province']) + ',' + str(df.iloc[i]['winery'])
```

If you want to correct the columns and force them to string, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092067/pandas-dataframe-convert-column-type-to-string-or-categorical/39092877#39092877).

Comment: req = df.iloc[i][str("country")]+','+ df.iloc[i][str("province")] +','+ df.iloc[i][str("winery")]


Should it look like this?

Comment: You would need to do the entire thing, not that part. I'll edit.

Comment: Great, please click the check mark next to my answer if it is working @OlgaOboiantseva

Answer (score 0):

Since the column types are a generic *object*, and since the error occurs at line 6, what is most likely happening is that, at some point, a value for either **country**, **province** or **winery** looks like a number even though it's supposed to be a string, and pandas reads it as a *float*.

You can solve this by casting all values to *string*, either the DataFrame column as a whole or when reading the values at line 6.