# Using Dictionary with in Pandas/PyArrow with Natural Keys

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I am using Parquet file format to store the structured version of raw data, received in CSV format. For this, I use Pandas to perform DataFrame manipulation, and Pyarrow to save the DataFrame in Parquet format. I also use pyarrow schema as a means to perform some level of data validation.

My challenge here is to convert a string column to categorical data type, and preferably I want to maintain the original codes in raw data. For example, if original data has column Gender `{ "M", "F" }` , I want to use `"M"` as code for `"Male"`, and `"F"` as code for `"Female"`. I don't want to use assigned numerical codes from `pd.Categorical` i.e. 0, 1. This may not be best practice from Kimball methodology perspective which advocates use of surrogate keys as opposed to natural keys, but it's what I want to achieve now.

In example below, I have the codes for `EmployeeCategory { "SR", "C", "M" }` and I have to create another column `EmployeeCategoryDescription` and store it together with the data. Is it possible to only store the original `EmployeeCategory`, but denotes it as a categorical and store its mapping somewhere as Parquet metadata?

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

df = pd.DataFrame(
{
    'Name': ['John', 'James', 'Jack', 'Jonathan', 'Jerry', 'Joseph'],
    'EmployeeCategory': ["SR","C","M","SR","M",pd.NA]
})

employeeCategoryMap = {
    "SR": "Senior",
    "C": "Consultant",
    "M": "Manager"
}

df['EmployeeCategoryDescription'] = df['EmployeeCategory'].map(employeeCategoryMap).fillna(pd.NA)

schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('Name', pa.string()),
    pa.field('EmployeeCategory', pa.string()),
    pa.field('EmployeeCategoryDescription', pa.string())
])

tbl = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema)

pq.write_table(tbl, 'test.parquet')
```

Comment: hi, not sure if this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092067/pandas-dataframe-convert-column-type-to-string-or-categorical

Comment: hi, it doesn't unfortunately. using categorical directly, I will get assigned categorical codes from pandas. I want to use my own category code M->Male, instead of 0 (assigned sequentially by pandas) ->M, or 0-> Male

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me where the employee category map is coming from.  However, if your goal is to store that alongside a column for later use then you could use field metadata.  [Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1T4rBC932ObD0vNIzQubOlp2lBWZ3Gv7M?usp=sharing) is a complete example.

The relevant pieces are:

Storing the metadata in the field metadata.

```
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
// Field metadata is a map from byte string to byte string
// so we need to serialize the map somehow.  Assuming it is
// a fairly simple map then json should work fine.
mapJson = json.dumps(employeeCategoryMap).encode('utf8')
// Fields and tables are immutable so we get a new field and then
// use it to create a new table.  I used 'categories' as a key but
// you can use whatever you want and you might want to namespace it
// with your project / company name for uniqueness
annotated_field = table.field('EmployeeCategory').with_metadata({b'categories': mapJson})
// Replacing a field requires the index but you could easily find that
// by name
annotated_table = table.set_column(1, annotated_field, table.column(1))
```

Retrieving and applying the categories

```
// We could grab the field directly but I'm pretending you have
// multiple fields with descriptions and don't know ahead of time
// which fields they are
for field in table_from_file.schema:
    field_metadata = field.metadata
    // Make sure to use b'' strings as keys
    if field_metadata is not None and b'categories' in field_metadata:
        // Deserialize the category information
        categories = json.loads(field_metadata[b'categories'])
        df[f'{field.name}Description'] = df[field.name].map(categories).fillna(pd.NA)
```

Comment: employeeCategoryMap may come from interviewing data steward or from documentation somewhere, not necessarily available in source systems.